# How to scale a recipe for Neapolitan Pizza?

Tags: pizza, recipe-scaling, neapolitan-pizza

I wanted to hopefully make the best Neapolitan pizza in my modest home. I attached the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tw0riOA4rDo) which contains the recipe for preparing the pizza.

However, the used amounts are too much for me. I wanted to prepare **2 pizzas**, so I wanted to scale down the used amounts by Chef Johnny.

Chef Johnny used 30 g of salt + 1 Kg of flour + 600 ml of water + 1 g of fresh yeast. With these amounts he said in the video he could make **up to 8 pizzas**.

So should I use a quarter of the amounts?

Answer (score 2):

In general bread formulas are proportional, and can be scaled as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using ¼ of everything should work.

As additional improvements for the scaling I also would recommend to measure all ingredients for the dough by weight as this allows to do the whole preparation with a scale only. As a next step you might want to consider to convert the recipe to [baker percentages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker_percentage) as this makes the scaling even easier.

Comment: The recipe is in weight already (considering that for water ml=g). But the advice about baker percentages is good.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to pizza cooking, but I note that the Associazione Verace Pizza Napoletana says that yeast should not be scaled proportionally (ie, that proportionally less yeast is needed as total quantities go up).  You can find their "official" recipe, and the commentary on yeast, within these regulations (written in English):

https://www.pizzanapoletana.org/public/pdf/disciplinare%202008%20UK.pdf